# How to define a smooth function of random bumps in a plane?

Tags: function-construction, random, generative-art, version-7

I would like to define a simple function that gives random smooth bumps in a plane, a bit like the clumsy picture below, but it should be continuous:

```
Plot3D[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

As a function of both $x$ and $y$, it should be smooth everywhere and be differentiable at least once.  How can we define such a function `RandomFun[x, y]` (pun intended) with Mathematica?

Ideally, it should be as simple as possible and be valid for Mathematcia 7 (`RandomFunction` doesn't seem to be recognized with this version).  Please, nothing fancy.  Just the simplest way to get smooth bumps of height between -1 and 1.

Comment: What's wrong with `tt = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}];ff = ListInterpolation[tt];Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick up the points

```
tt = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}];
```

Interpolate

```
ff = Interpolation[Flatten[tt, 1], Method -> "Spline"];
```

Plot

```
Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

More points

```
tt = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 5, 0.25}, {y, 0, 5, 
   0.25}];    ff = Interpolation[Flatten[tt, 1], Method -> "Spline"];
Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None];
```

[image]

So if you want to wrap it up

```
Randfun:= 
 Module[{tt = 
    Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {x, 0, 5, 1}, {y, 0, 5, 1}]},
  Interpolation[Flatten[tt, 1], Method -> "Spline"]
  ]
```

Then

```
Table[Plot3D[Randfun[x, y] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All], {2}, {2}]
```

[image]

Conversely, if you want to keep the same random bumps

```
ff1 = Randfun[x, y];
Table[ContourPlot[ff1, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}], {2}]
```

[image]

If you want only a few point above sea level:

```
tt = Table[{x, y, z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]; If[z > 0.75, z, 0]}, {x, 0, 5, 1/2}, {y, 0, 5, 1/2}];
ff = Interpolation[Flatten[tt, 1], Method -> "Spline"];
Plot3D[ff[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None,
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's a proper solution!  Thanks a lot!  I'll mark your answer after a while, in case someone else find something prettier.

Comment: What to add, if you need the random bumps to stay the same, after a first pass?

Comment: Ok, it's trivial: **SeedRandom[0]**.  Sorry for this.  But your answer is awesome!

Comment: I am wondering, your function is everywhere hilly. Can one use your method to have essentially a flat plane with some random bumps here and there?

Comment: @yarchik it seems that, to my understanding, what you’re asking for is dependent upon the domain of the plane you’re displaying relative to the range chosen for the `RandomReal` function being used.