# How to insert variable height in this random bumps function?

Tags: function-construction, random, parametric-functions, generative-art, version-7

I'm trying to insert a "time" variable that control the height of the random smooth bumps, but I'm yet unable to do it right, as shown with the code below:

```
(*SeedRandom[0]*)
(* Third coordinate in the table should be dependant on the time parameter: *)

RandomPoints = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}] + (* t RandomReal[{-10, 10}] *)}, {x, -30, 30, 8}, {y, -30, 30, 8}];

RandomBumps = Interpolation[Flatten[RandomPoints, 1], Method -> "Spline"];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate[RandomBumps[x, y]],
  {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30},
  PlotPoints -> 20,
  MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &)},
  MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.25],
  ImageSize -> 700
  ],
 {
  t, 0, 20, 0.1,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"},
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}
  },
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 FrameMargins -> None,
 FrameLabel ->  {None, None, 
   Style["Funny Title Here!", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
 ]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

I need the time parameter in the `Manipulate` box to randomly change the height of the bumps.  Currently, it's doing nothing.  What am I doing wrong here?

The smooth random bumps function is an answer from chris here: [How to define a smooth function of random bumps in a plane?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236204/how-to-define-a-smooth-function-of-random-bumps-in-a-plane?noredirect=1#comment596480_236204)

Comment: Your code doesn't work as pasted. See if you really pasted what you have in your notebook. Also, do NOT use user-defined variables with uppercase names, particularly when your name is only one letter away from a built-in function (e.g.`RandomPoint`).

Comment: @MarcoB, I removed the $t$ culprit in the function.  It should work now.  About the uppercase, I know that I may encounter some conflicts, but my names are usually in French, and it's an habit to use uppercase for my functions.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2:** If you don't need the mesh lines, the surface can be rendered very fast using `BSplineSurface` + `Graphics3D` (rather than `Interpolation` + Plot3D`):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Orange, EdgeForm[], BSplineSurface @ 
  Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}] + t RandomReal[{-10, 10 }]}, 
     {x, -30, 30, 8}, {y, -30, 30, 8}]}, 
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}, {-200, 200}}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1], {t, 0, 20, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[randomPoints, randomBumps]
randomPoints[t_] := Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{-1, 1}] + t RandomReal[{-10, 10}] },
   {x, -30, 30, 8}, {y, -30, 30, 8}];

randomBumps[t_] := Interpolation[Flatten[randomPoints[t], 1], Method -> "Spline"];

Manipulate[Plot3D[Evaluate[randomBumps[t][x, y]], {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30}, 
  PlotPoints -> 20, MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &)}, 
  MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.25], ImageSize -> 500], {t, 0, 20, 0.1, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom, FrameMargins -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
   Style["Funny Title Here!", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Pre-computing the interpolating functions outside `Manipulate` should make it more responsive:

```
ClearAll[randomBumps]
rbumplist =  Association[# -> Interpolation[Flatten[randomPoints[#], 1], 
       Method -> "Spline"] & /@ Range[0, 20, 1/10]];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[rbumplist[t][x, y]], {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30}, 
  PlotPoints -> 20, MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &)}, 
  MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.25], ImageSize -> 500, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, 20, 1/10, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}}, 
 TrackedSymbols -> {t}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom, 
 FrameMargins -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
   Style["Funny Title Here!", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The time variable doesn't make the shape to change continuously.  Is it differentiable?

Comment: I mean that the shape should change continuously while drawing the time slider.

Comment: @Cham, I don't how to think about  _continuously_ and _differentiable_ when `t` is discrete and you are randomly perturbing the input list for every `t`. Re the responsiveness to slider to moves, there is a trade-off between the quality of rendering while you move the slider and control responsiveness.

Comment: About the continuity and differentiability, it's because I'll need to use that fonction to define random initial and boundary conditions in a consistent way.  The initial conditions need the derivative of the random field, evaluated at time 0.  Maybe there's another and simpler way in doing it, but I don't see it.