# Randomly oscillating surface is not working well

Tags: function-construction, random, parametric-functions, generative-art, version-7

I'm trying to built some random moving surface from a plane perturbed with random oscillators, and my current code isn't doing what I need yet, as seen from the `Manipulate` box.  I'm building the surface from an answer found here :

[How to insert variable height in this random bumps function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236232/how-to-insert-variable-height-in-this-random-bumps-function/236234?noredirect=1#comment596570_236234)

Here's the code:

```
Clear["Global`*"] 

amplitude[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}]
frequency[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.25, 0.75}]
phase[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0, 2Pi}]

randomPoints[t_] := Table[{x, y, amplitude[x, y]Sin[frequency[x, y]t + phase[x, y]]}, {x, -30, 30, 5}, {y, -30, 30, 5}];

randomBumps[t_] := Interpolation[Flatten[randomPoints[t], 1], Method -> "Spline"];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
 Evaluate[randomBumps[t][x, y]],
  {x, -10, 10},
  {y, -10, 10},
  PlotPoints -> 30,
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]],
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  MeshFunctions -> {(#3&)},
  MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.25],
  ImageSize -> 700
  ],
 {
  t, 0, 20, 0.01,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"},
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}
  },
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 FrameMargins -> None,
 FrameLabel ->  {None, None, 
   Style["Some Funny Title", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
 ]
```

Preview, with some of the issue shown in red:

[image]

When I move the time slider, the surface shown above is wildly jumping in random ways, and it's not what I'm trying to do.

Consider the surface as a set of oscillators, a single one at each location of the $x \, y$ grid.  The oscillators have a fixed **random frequency** $f$, **random amplitude** $A$ and **random phase** $\phi$.  Once the code is run, the amplitudes, frequencies and phases are randomly selected and an interpolation surface is drawn from the resulting positions at time $t = 0$.  For the next time step, *these numbers shouldn't change*.  Each point of the surface should be smoothly oscillating vertically (with their fixed amplitudes, frequencies and phases).  Currently, the `Manipulate` box isn't showing this behavior: the numbers $A$, $f$ and $\phi$ appears to change randomly a each time step.

Or maybe it's the Spline Interpolation which creates a new surface at each time step?

How can I fix this issue?

Take note that I need the surface to be **smooth** and **differentiable** everywhere, for the three variables $x$, $y$ and $t$ (except at the edges).

Answer (score 3):

The main bug is that you specify randomBumps[t_] := ... instead of randomBumps[t_] = ... This creates a new surface every time the time changes.

Further, you have some syntax errors. Here is a corrected version:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

amplitude[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}]
frequency[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.25, 0.75}]
phase[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]

randomPoints[t_] = 
  Table[{x, y, 
    amplitude[x, y] Sin[frequency[x, y] t + phase[x, y]]}, {x, -30, 
    30, 5}, {y, -30, 30, 5}];

randomBumps[t_] = Interpolation[Flatten[randomPoints[t], 1]];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[randomBumps[t][x, y]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> 30, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &)}, MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.25], 
  ImageSize -> 700], {t, 0, 20, 0.01}, 
 AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom, FrameMargins -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
   Style["Some Funny Title", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}]
```

Comment: What were the other syntax errors?

Comment: I noticed that you removed Method -> "Spline".  Why?  Was this necessary to get a smooth and differentiable surface?

Comment: I'm unable to make the derivative of the randomBumps function, relative to any of its three variables.

Comment: I removed "Spline" because you can not do a spline interpolation with a unknown parameter t. But to precalculate the interpolation is crucial for a speedy calculation of the graphics.  If you want derivatives, maybe  you should reformulate  the code with: randomBumps[t,x, y].